# Getting proj string from cartopy CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, proj, cartopy

I'm trying to get proj strings from cartopy crs', such as `cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()`.  I can manually infer the proj string from [the **init**() function in the source code](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/_modules/cartopy/crs.html#PlateCarree) but I need to query it, so I can apply it to a tiff file with gdal.

I'm trying to avoid adding modules outside from scipy, numpy, gdal, cartopy, OWSLib, MatPlotLib, and Pillow.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To get `proj string` of `cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()` projection, one can run this code:

```
import cartopy
cartopy.crs.PlateCarree().proj4_init
```

the output will be:

'+ellps=WGS84 +a=57.29577951308232 +proj=eqc +lon_0=0.0 +no_defs'